# Modules, Mathematica

Tags: module, matrix, sum

I have the following problem:
I want to sum a smaller matrix M to a bigger one , N, starting from i,j in N.

Here is the code:

```
PutMintoN[M_, Q_, i_, j_] := Module[{Mrow, Mcol},
   {Mrow, Mcol} = Dimensions[M];
   For[k = 1, k <= Mrow, k++,
    For[q = 1, q <= Mcol, q++,
     Q[[i + k - 1, j + q - 1]] = 
      Q[[i + k - 1, j + q - 1]] + M[[k, q]]]];
   Q
   ];
```

The problem seems not to be in the algorithm, but in the module because if i copy the inner code outside , it works.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found out why. Q as a parameter of the function can't change during the iterations. It must be definied it's copy and to work with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Great, that you found your error on your own.

I produced a more elegant and robust Module for the same purpose, by the use of **ArrayPad**, to bring M to the same Dimension as N and than just Add M to N. It even works, if i or j runns out of the dimensions of N, wich is a problem for your original module.

```
putMintoN[M_, N_, i_, j_] := Module[{Mrow, Mcol, Nrow, Ncol, mn},
  {Mrow, Mcol} = Dimensions[M]; {Nrow, Ncol} = Dimensions[N];
  mn = {{Min[i - 1, Nrow], Min[(Nrow - Mrow) - i + 1, Nrow]}, 
        {Min[j - 1, Ncol], Min[(Ncol - Mcol) - j + 1, Ncol]}};
  ArrayPad[M, mn] + N]
```

test:

```
IN: putMintoN[{{x, y, p}, {z, w, q}}, {{a, b, c}, {d, e, f}, {g, h, i}, {j, k, l}}, 2, 1]
OUT: {{a, b, c}, {d + x, e + y, f + p}, {g + z, h + w, i + q}, {j, k, l}}
```

In Mathematica it is often possible to avoid the use of for-lopes, with Listable functions, map, apply, and so on.

Hope this inspires you.
Best regards.